# Curl URL and post results in Excel cell?

Tags: json, excel, vba, curl

I have 200 rows in an Excel sheet that I would like to include in a curl (or any kind of HTTP get) and see the results in a second column.

```
**Column A**
123
456
789
012
...
```

I have tried using the Excel option to get data from an external web page but it doesn't appear to work for multiple row on the same sheet. Is there a way for me to append the value in Column A to a static URL (ie:http://testurl.net/page.php?ID=[Column A]) so that the result of the page is shown in Column B? I know the response from the URL will be a rest response that will display only a couple words.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this by using a http request object:

```
Dim oRequest As Object
Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.cboden.de"
oRequest.Send
MsgBox oRequest.ResponseText
```

If you are behind a proxy you can use something like this:

```
Const HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY = 2
Dim oRequest As Object
Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oRequest.setProxy HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY, "http://proxy.intern:8080"
oRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.cboden.de"
oRequest.Send
MsgBox oRequest.ResponseText
```

and if you want to use POST (instead of the GET method) to pass some values to the webserver, you can try this:

```
Dim oRequest As Object
Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oRequest.Open "POST", "http://www.cboden.de/misc/posttest.php"
oRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Typ", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oRequest.Send "var1=123&anothervar=test"
MsgBox oRequest.ResponseText
```

if you put it into a function then you can use it in you worksheet:

```
Function getCustomHyperlink(ByVal pURL As String) As String
    Dim oRequest As Object
    Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    oRequest.Open "GET", pURL
    oRequest.Send
    getCustomHyperlink = oRequest.ResponseText
End Function
```

within the worksheet you can then say for example:

```
=getCustomHyperlink("https://www.google.com/search?q=" & A1 )
```

if your search value is in A1

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway to append the value of a column to that URL?

Comment: simply put the code into a function, pass the URL as parameter to it and return the content of the requested page. You can then use that funtion directly in the worksheet

Comment: I think I am following you but this doesn't seem to be working: Function CustomHyperlink(Term)

Dim oRequest As Object
Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.google.com" & Term
oRequest.Send
CustomHyperlink = oRequest.ResponseText

End Function

Comment: ok ... I expanded my answer above with a working solution. Some remarks to your attempt: first you always should define the datatypes for your parameters and for the return value. Second it's always good to use explicit ByVal or ByRef. Third: you had an additional semicolon behind your web address ... that couldn't work. And last but not least: I guess it's better to have a generic function that can work for all URL's. Therefore it's better to put parts of the URL NOT in the function but in the calling statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the WEBSERVICE(url)

[image]

Comment: This is great, so long as authentication is not required.