# Run Curl Commands in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, curl

I'm trying to figure out a way to pass variables into cURL commands (maybe this will interact with Ubuntu, or the CMD window, or something else; not totally sure).

I have some cURL commands like this:

```
curl -X "GET" -H "Authorization: Bearer API_Key" "https://url-plat-api/drives/my"
```

Now, I want to pass in my API_Key ID and run the cURL command.

Also, I have some cURL commands like this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer API_Key" "https://url-plat-api/identities/email/me@gmail@corp.com"
```

Here, I want to pass in the API_Key and the emailID, and run the cURL command.

How can I run these cURL commands in Excel?  Eventually I will select items from a ComboBox, and pass these variables into a VBA command, and run that.  I can do these things very easily.  How can I set up the VBA script to interact with cURL?

Comment: Nothing really built into Excel. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26681866/4996248) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17063550/4996248) might help.

Comment: In addition to what @JohnColeman provided, which is probably the way to go, if you really want to use cURL, then you can write curl commands into `.bat` files and run those via vba.

Comment: What is the end purpose and can these not be replaced with WinHTTP/XMLHTTP requests? You are familiar with these so I guess there is a reason.